Sending EIP-712 message to Safe
I'm trying to add a EIP-712 message with APIKit.
The message has the following structure:
const name = await debtToken.call("name");
    const version = "1";
    const nonce = await debtToken.call("nonces", [await signer.getAddress()]);
    const chainId = chain.chainId;
    const deadline = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600; // 1 hour from now

    const domain = {
      name,
      version,
      chainId,
      verifyingContract: debtTokenAddress,
    };

    const types = {
      DelegationWithSig: [
        { name: "delegatee", type: "address" },
        { name: "value", type: "uint256" },
        { name: "nonce", type: "uint256" },
        { name: "deadline", type: "uint256" },
      ],
    };

    const decimals = await debtToken.call("decimals");

    const message = {
      delegatee: SkylineDigitalLoanManagerAddresses[chainId],
      value: ethers.utils.parseUnits(amount, decimals).toString(),
      nonce: nonce.toString(),
      deadline,
    };

Creating the message works by using:
let safeMessage = safeProtocolKit.createMessage({
        domain,
        types,
        message,
      });

But then when I tried to "push" it with addMessage, the types on addMessage didn't support an array, which seems incorrect.
const response = await safeApiService.addMessage(safeAddress, {
        message: {
          domain,
          types, // Error: Type '{ DelegationWithSig: { name: string; type: string; }[]; }' is missing the following properties from type 'TypedDataField': name, type
          message,
        },
        signature: buildSignatureBytes([signedSafeMessage.signatures.get(personalWalletAddress.toLowerCase()) as any])
      });

I tried to force any as type but the API returned an error saying: "Provided dictionary is not a valid EIP712 message"
Edit: primaryType is only available at createMessage method it isn't available at addMessage, by looking at the type we can confirm that:
addMessage(safeAddress: string, addMessageProps: AddMessageProps): Promise<void>;

export type AddMessageProps = {
    message: string | EIP712TypedData;
    safeAppId?: number;
    signature: string;
}

export type EIP712TypedData = {
    domain: TypedDataDomain;
    types: TypedDataField;
    message: Record<string, unknown>;
};

export interface TypedDataField {
    name: string;
    type: string;
}

The issue seems to be here, there's no primaryType and types property that expects an object instead of a list of objects (function parameters).
In my PoV this should match the same type/structure as in createMessage type and EIP-712 standard.
createMessage(message: string | EIP712TypedData): SafeMessage;

export interface EIP712TypedData {
    domain: TypedDataDomain;
    types: TypedMessageTypes; // Here is correct
    message: Record<string, unknown>;
    primaryType?: string; // Exists
}

type TypedMessageTypes = {
    [key: string]: TypedDataTypes[];
}

interface TypedDataTypes {
    name: string;
    type: string;
}

Edit 2 (HTTP request):
HTTP:
POST https://safe-transaction-sepolia.safe.global/api/v1/safes/0x0/messages/
Body:
{"message":{"domain":{"name":"Aave Ethereum Variable Debt USDC","version":"1","chainId":11155111,"verifyingContract":"0x0"},"types":{"DelegationWithSig":[{"name":"delegatee","type":"address"},{"name":"value","type":"uint256"},{"name":"nonce","type":"uint256"},{"name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}]},"message":{"delegatee":"0x0","value":"10000000000","nonce":"1","deadline":1727365380}},"signature":"0x0"}

Response:
{
    "message": [
        "Provided dictionary is not a valid EIP712 message {'domain': {'name': 'Aave Ethereum Variable Debt USDC', 'version': '1', 'chainId': 11155111, 'verifyingContract': '0x0'}, 'types': {'DelegationWithSig': [{'name': 'delegatee', 'type': 'address'}, {'name': 'value', 'type': 'uint256'}, {'name': 'nonce', 'type': 'uint256'}, {'name': 'deadline', 'type': 'uint256'}]}, 'message': {'delegatee': '0x0', 'value': '10000000000', 'nonce': '1', 'deadline': 1727365380}}"
    ]
}

I have omitted the addresses for security reasons. But I can send it in private via Discord.

Your message structure is missing a required primaryType, maybe adding could solve your problem; if not, it could be useful to add to your post the payload of the API call that fires the error, so we can best assist you.
Please let me know! Thanks in advance  Best, Louis

Hey Louis, thanks for replying. I edit the question with answers.

Thank you for that! You are correct, I will be looping the team on this. Would it be possible for you to also catch the data being sent to the API? Thank you very much in advance

Added, thank you.

Thank you for that! Would it be possible to also include the rest of the API call payload (not only the body), so we can replicate the call? This data will enable us to go to the bottom of the issue. Thank you in advance  Best, Louis

Add that also, any update? Thank you

Any update @Louis?
